# Why does the import of a package (mongoose) lead to a ReferenceError in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

When trying to run the following code in [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`. If I remove the `const mongoose = require('mongoose');` line, everything works well. It's worth noting that I have installed `mongoose` using the `npm i mongoose` command (version `6.3.1`).

```js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export default class Test extends React.Component {

        render() {
                return (
                        <div>
                                <p>Hey StackOverflow!</p>
                        </div>
                );
        }
}
```

What is the cause of this problem? Is it a problem with the `mongoose` package specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need mongoose in your frontend code in the first place?
To answer your question specifically:
mongoose is using the global `process` variable which is only available in a NodeJS context (e.g. a backend server application), not Browser context.

Comment: I'm trying read the data located in my MongoDB database so I can display it in the front-end.